# Update status bar when receiving message?

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I am quite new to GUI design and struggle to communicae with my core application.

I have a Thread that I use to run my core code. It is started when the user clicks on a start button.
On the other side,  I have my gui; and I would like it to be updated during the process.

My Thread currently populates a Queue, and I want to set the messages of this Queue in the status bar.

Currently, I use :

```
     while not self.stopPull:
         try:
             print self.mess_queue.get() # would set my status bar
         except Queue.Empty:
            continue
```

The Thread code is really basic:

```
    while not self.stoprequest.isSet():
            bla()#some processing . . .
            self.result_q.put("bla")
            bla()#some other processing . . .
            self.result_q.put("blabla")
```

Thing is, this is of course blocking . . .

So do I have to create another Thread to listen to new messages in my Queue, or is there a way to have some kind of interruptions as a new message is pulled ?

Once again, I am completely ignorant with communication process, and I must miss some basic keywords, because I couldn't find documentation on the subject on the web.

Thank you for your hel !

Comment: Ok, seems like this is a start : http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=all#20.1 . Adding Threads seem to be valid solution then

Comment: `queue.get()` has a `nowait` option that throws the `empty` exception _instead_ of blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a GUI to be non blocking, one has to use threads.

The pygtk FAQ has a part dedicated to this : 
http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=all#20.1